# Unable to upgrade ruby due to leveldb

Tags: ruby, macos, leveldb

I need to upgrade `ruby` :

```
bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.5
```

So let's go do that:

```
brew upgrade ruby
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated Homebrew from 5354ba84e to 203f8d66a.
```

Oh but hit the brakes here:

```
Error: Failed to import:
 /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb
leveldb: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting keyword_end
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting keyword_end
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting keyword_end
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/leveldb.rb:52: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting keyword_end
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  ^
Error: Failed to import: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb
glog: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected <<
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ===
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected >>
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting keyword_end
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb:73: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting keyword_end
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/glog.rb:75: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
Error: Failed to import: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb
snappy: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting keyword_end
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting keyword_end
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
  ^
Error: Failed to import: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/opencv.rb
opencv: cannot load such file -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/Requirements/cuda_requirement
```

And our verdict:

```
 Error: ruby not installed
```

From the following github issue:  https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel/issues/95   I tried

```
$brew uninstall leveldb
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/leveldb/1.19... (26 files, 1.1MB)
11:31:49/aact $brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/86c8b39428a4e485e8afcc02f2e31da9d53007a0/Formula/leveldb.rb
```

But the end result was the same:

```
==> Consider using `brew extract leveldb ...`!
This will extract your desired leveldb version to a stable tap instead of
installing from an unstable URL!

######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: snappy: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
  ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting keyword_end
=======
   ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/snappy.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected >>, expecting keyword_end
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

Any pointers how to get this ruby upgrade completed?

Comment: Looks like you have merge conflict markers in your files indicating a previous merge had conflicts which were not resolved but simply committed. You should undo that bad merge. For managing Ruby consider RVM instead. https://rvm.io/

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.4.5`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: @anothermh ok - been a long long time since I did ruby myself. Sad: great language..